# Lightweight alternatives to firebug lite

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, inspect, firebug-lite

The website I'm debugging in ie6 has lots and lots of inefficient legacy code and when I try and run firebug lite to try and figure out a tricky hasLayout issue it crashes ie6.

Is there an alternative to firebug lite which simply recreates firebug's html tab and inspect element features?

*edit* I tried [MODI](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2007/11/13/modi-the-lightweight-dom-inspector-bookmarklet/), but as it only offers an inspect feature, with no DOM traversal, it's useless for debugging elements which aren't showing up on the screen because of a hasLayout bug.

Comment: You could go debugging the good old way by removing and adding problematic elements. There is a set of properties that trigger hasLayout - just start applying those and add in and out your problematic elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an alternative to firebug lite which simply recreates
>   firebug's html tab and inspect element features?

Try the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359), which you can install for IE6/7.

Later versions of IE include the very similar [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of it myself! Also reminded me about http://www.debugbar.com/, which is also pretty good.